# Re-start download api csv file Python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to create a function to download a file if the timeout of the url fail. My problem is the timeout of the url because sometimes the csv files take more time that it so I need to try and try and try to download. I add point of re start on my funtion then `"FAIL...` but it try one time only!

`28` lines is the lines that you have when the timeout fail.

```
def main():
    este_mes('https://a.net/admin/adnet/pub/stats/informe.csv?fechashortcut_id=0&fecha_inicio=31/12/2017&fecha_fin={}'.format(fecha) + '&intipo_id=16&informe_id=955&o=csv')

    este_mes_pais('https://a.net/admin/adnet/pub/stats/informe.csv?fechashortcut_id=0&fecha_inicio=01/01/2018&fecha_fin={}'.format(fecha) + '&intipo_id=16&informe_id=752&o=csv')
    f = open("este_mes_pais.csv")
    numlines = len(f.readlines())
    if numlines <= 28:
        print "FAIL, reintentando..."
        este_mes_pais('https://a.net/admin/adnet/pub/stats/informe.csv?fechashortcut_id=0&fecha_inicio=01/01/2018&fecha_fin={}'.format(fecha) + '&intipo_id=16&informe_id=752&o=csv')
    else:
        print "este_mes_pais Descargado"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `while` loop with a `True` condition will do. Break from the loop if the number of lines is above 28 (note that could be done without reading the whole file with an iterator), else print an error message and keep the loop running:

```
while True:
    este_mes_pais('https://a.net/admin/adnet/pub/stats/informe.csv?fechashortcut_id=0&fecha_inicio=01/01/2018&fecha_fin={}'.format(fecha) + '&intipo_id=16&informe_id=752&o=csv')
    with open("este_mes_pais.csv") as f:
        #numlines = len(f.readlines())  # classic approach
        # faster if the file is big, won't read more than 29 lines
        numlines = sum(next(f,None) is not None for _ in range(29))

    if numlines <= 28:
        print "FAIL, reintentando..."
    else:
        break  # OK, get out of the loop
```

Comment: okey but `if numlines <= 28:`I need to try to download the csv again and in your function is it happen?

Comment: the loop restarts the download. `break` gets out of the loop when the number of lines is > 28. try it out.